# Can ninject be used to configure class based inject (instead of interface)?

Tags: c#, ninject

Can Ninject be used to configure non-interfaced based injection?

```
public EntityController([Named("EntityServiceName")] EntityService service)
```

instead of

```
public EntityController([Named("EntityServiceName")] IEntityService service)
```

I'm trying to do just this and running into problems, and was wondering if the issue was that I'm not using interfaces.

Additional info:
Maybe I'm off here, but here is the benefit we're hoping for:
We're following a DDD pattern with an onion/ports and adapters architecture, so we have a domain project with concrete domain objects and domain services as well as external interfaces defined, an infrastructure project which implements the external interfaces defined in the domain, and finally a web api project for exposing them.

The controllers of the web api need to have an instance of the domain services injected into them. But since there would be a 1:1 relationship between the interface and the domain service, it seems like unnecessary bloat to just add interfaces for the domain services.

So there is really no benefit to making an interface for the domain services, but I would still like to configure and inject them via Ninject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can... yes. But there's not much it accomplishes. Here's an example:

```
kernel.Bind<List<string>>().ToConstant(new List<string>(){"Foo", "Bar"});
```

But if you're not using an Interface, you're not really getting much benefit of Dependency Injection.  And obviously this accomplishes nothing over ICollection. I suppose you could use it to set default class values, and still get the advantage of unit testing... but doing so with Interfaces will usually be much better, since you can do much better mocking. I would only do this for the most basic of classes.

Comment: Why are you not getting much benefit out of it? In my case I have a controller in the web project which is injected with a service which resides in the core project which needs to be injected with an IRepository (the interface is also defined in the core project) implementation defined in the infrastructure project. The domain service does need to be injected into the controller, but there is really no other benefit to having an interface for it. Mocking is accomplished with virtual methods (as was recommended in some other threads). Am I missing something here?

Comment: This answer did turn out to be correct, you can inject concrete classes with Ninject. Still not sure why it wouldn't be beneficial in some cases though.